# Error with odata response for angular 2 template interpolation for @ symbol

Tags: angular, odata

I am fetching data from an odata Web API (which I do not have control over).

In the response is a standard summary of the odata returned such as `@odata.context` and `@odata.count`.

I am trying to include statistics in my angular 2 html template, but it seems the `@` is an illegal character when I try the following:

`There are {{ results.@odata.count }} results to your query`

It results in the following error:

`Template parse errors: Unexpected character [@] at column...`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript variable/object property cannot starts with `@` character. Try `results['@odata'].count` or even `results['@odata.count']` (depending on how you convert response to object)